# HTML images stored in res/drawable not displaying in release apk

Tags: android, html, xslt, apk

I have several images which are stored in res/drawable and are displayed via HTML in a WebView for printing.

They show up fine when running the app from Android Studio but fail to load in the release apk.

The images are included in the release apk (I unzipped the apk to check they are there).

Why are they not displaying correctly in the release application?

The images are retrieved via an XSLT transformation to HTML as follows:

```
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/image_1.png"/>
```

And the images are in `release_apk/res/drawable/image_1.png` in the apk.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why they aren't accessible, in the end I had to move the images to the assets folder.

Perhaps something to do with Minify?